# go - `__GI___pthread_mutex_unlock` takes most of the execution time when using cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm using cgo to call a C function from Go. Inside the C function there is a callback to a Go function. In other way, I'm calling Go -> C -> Go.

After running pprof, I noticed that the `__GI___pthread_mutex_unlock` took half of the execution time. AFAIK, cgo has an overhead, especially calling back from C to Go. But it's weird that cgo takes half of the execution time to do some locking. Is there something wrong in my code?

`main.go`

```
package main

/*
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

extern void go_get_value(uint8_t* key32, uint8_t *value32);

void get_value(uint8_t* key32, uint8_t *value32) {
    uint8_t value[32];
    go_get_value(key32, value);
    memcpy(value32, value, 32);
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/pkg/profile"

    _ "github.com/ianlancetaylor/cgosymbolizer"
)

func getValue(key [32]byte) []byte {
    key32 := (*C.uint8_t)(C.CBytes(key[:]))
    value32 := (*C.uint8_t)(C.malloc(32))
    C.get_value(key32, value32)
    ret := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(value32), 32)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(key32))
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(value32))
    return ret
}

func main() {
    defer profile.Start().Stop()

    numWorkers := runtime.NumCPU()
    fmt.Printf("numWorkers = %v\n", numWorkers)
    numTasks := 10_000_000
    tasks := make(chan struct{}, numTasks)
    for i := 0; i < numTasks; i++ {
        tasks <- struct{}{}
    }
    close(tasks)
    start := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for range tasks {
                value := getValue([32]byte{})
                _ = value
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("took %vms\n", time.Since(start).Milliseconds())
}
```

`callback.go`

```
package main

/*
#include <stdint.h>

extern void go_get_value(uint8_t* key32, uint8_t *value32);
*/
import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

func copyToCbytes(src []byte, dst *C.uint8_t) {
    n := len(src)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        *(*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(dst)) + uintptr(i))) = (C.uint8_t)(src[i])
    }
}

//export go_get_value
func go_get_value(key32 *C.uint8_t, value32 *C.uint8_t) {
    key := C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(key32), 32)
    _ = key
    value := make([]byte, 32)
    copyToCbytes(value, value32)
}
```

Running enviroment:

`lscpu`

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          32
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-31
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              16
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           79
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                        0
CPU MHz:                         2200.152
BogoMIPS:                        4400.30
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       512 KiB
L1i cache:                       512 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
L3 cache:                        55 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-31
...
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtop
                                 ology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowpre
                                 fetch invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear arch_capabilities
```

Golang version

```
go version go1.20.5 linux/amd64
```

Here is the pprof result:
[image]

EDIT: added running environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I could not reproduce it with your program above:

```
 ± go1.20.5 tool pprof /tmp/profile3378726905/cpu.pprof
File: callback
Build ID: e295a7c26f8d6b18641985f09c9fa3872b3ae569
Type: cpu
Time: Jun 20, 2023 at 12:41pm (+07)
Duration: 3.08s, Total samples = 19.49s (632.73%)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 11520ms, 59.11% of 19490ms total
Dropped 120 nodes (cum <= 97.45ms)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 88
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    2320ms 11.90% 11.90%     2320ms 11.90%  __GI___lll_lock_wake
    2170ms 11.13% 23.04%     2170ms 11.13%  futex_wait (inline)
    1750ms  8.98% 32.02%     1750ms  8.98%  runtime.procyield
    1010ms  5.18% 37.20%     1240ms  6.36%  runtime.casgstatus
     950ms  4.87% 42.07%     1060ms  5.44%  runtime.reentersyscall
     870ms  4.46% 46.54%     3480ms 17.86%  lll_mutex_lock_optimized (inline)
     740ms  3.80% 50.33%     1900ms  9.75%  runtime.mallocgc
     610ms  3.13% 53.46%     4090ms 20.99%  ___pthread_mutex_lock
     570ms  2.92% 56.39%      810ms  4.16%  runtime.exitsyscallfast
     530ms  2.72% 59.11%     2220ms 11.39%  runtime.lock2
```

But there's a [global mutex](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.20/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit.c#L18) for every callbacks, so that would kill the performance if you do parallel callbacks.

Comment: I ran it again with NumCPUs = 8 and got a similar result as your (https://pastebin.com/sjmxyba3). The result in my question is ran with NumCPUs = 32. I also added `lscpu` output and Golang version to my question.

Comment: >> But there's a global mutex for every callbacks, so that would kill the performance if you do parallel callbacks.


The mutex usage scope looks small, seem won't kill too much performance to me.

Comment: @secmask see https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/rgKT2ptyeGQ/m/ceZ2VwqTBAAJ

Comment: @phqb I filed https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60961 and sent https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/505455. Please try that patch and let me know if the contention is reduced. Thank you.

Comment: @cuonglm The patch reduced `__GI___pthread_mutex_unlock` to 17% when running on the environment in the question. Here is pprof top https://pastebin.com/wswARgS1. Thank you for the patch.